# How to use webfont with @font-face

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2, font-face, webfonts

I want to change the font in my application to a custom font but the following code is not working:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: "ArnoProBold"; 
src: url("resources/fonts/ArnoProBold.ttf");
}
@font-face 
{
 font-family: "ArnoProCaption"; 
 src: url("resources/fonts/ArnoProCaption.ttf");
}
@font-face 
{
 font-family: "Arn";
 src: url("resources/fonts/ArnoProLightDisplay.ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey @Ritesh please try something like this,

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'ArnoProBold';
   src: url('resources/fonts/your_file.eot');
   src: url('resources/fonts/fonts?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('resources/fonts/your_file.woff') format('woff'),
        url('resources/fonts/your_file.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('resources/fonts/your_file.svg#ArnoProBold') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

and so on.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: hey i have applied this css in index file ,when iam applying this font text not displaying,is there any other option,if we add this in app.css there also not working

Comment: How do these apply in your files? In app.css file just put `font` like this, e.g.: `label { font: ArnoProBold; }` or `.your_class { font: ArnoProBold; font-size: 12px;}`. I hope this helps. ;)

Comment: Whats that `ArnoProBold`, while having `font-weight: normal` ?